# Azure SQL DB: Failover secondary DB is read-only

Tags: database, azure, azure-sql-database

Thank you in advance...

I created a failover group and want to test a failover. I force a failover through the failover group tab and it says it is successful and the Secondary DB is now the Primary. However, when I try to write to it I get this error:

Error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Failed to update database "PTextingDvlp" because the database is read-only.

My understanding is that once the secondary DB becomes primary it is read/write.

Does anyone know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose to use **failover** with **Azure SQL** you may not notice that the **connectionstring** changes.

So you will need to use the **correct connectionstring**, the one that points to the **read/write listener endpoint**.

You can find this by in you azure portal at:

```
Dashboard > All resources > yourgeoname - Failover groups > yourgeoFailover
```

Scroll to the bottom and you'll see your **Read/Write** listener endpoint and your **Read-only** listener endpoint.

Change your connectionstrings to use one of these, if you want to write then choose the Read/Write one. This will always point at the active db no matter which failover is used.

Additionally, if you need to simply **Read** data then you can use the Read only connectionString as load balancing. Thereby reducing load on the **Read/Write** db.

Comment: To clarify, you need to change the endpoint in your connection string from myserver.database.windows.net (where myserver is the ORIGINAL sql server) to the FAILOVER GROUP!  So, myserverfo.database.windows.net.  That was not clear to me but Alex Stephens got me to where I could figure it out.  Thanks ALEX!

Answer (score 1):

When you failover, as you mentioned, the primary DB becomes secondary and also read only. The connection string to the new primary changes as a result of the failover.

It is more that likely that your connection string is still pointing to the original DB which is now read only.

**Solution:** Please check that you have updated the connection string to point to the new primary to be able to make the updates.

**Reference**: [Active geo-replication and auto-failover groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-geo-replication-overview#best-practices-of-using-failover-groups-for-business-continuity)